# Cart rule in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created cart with following conditions 
[image]

I have added one configurable product under category 3. But its not working .. If anything add to configure?

Comment: What i can see in your condition is that you have NOT for category 3 which means it will not apply that rule for the products belonging to category 3 which is correct as per my understanding. Or are you saying that rule is getting applied to the products belonging to the category id 3?

Comment: Yes. it will not apply that rule for the products belonging to category 3

Answer (score 0):

You did the mistake, as per as screenshot, your condition**is  not**.It should be IS or contain

[image]

Comment: i dont need that

Comment: Means? donot understand

Comment: When i have use the "is not" condition ?

Comment: As my screenshot,when the simple product of this configurable product was tagged with category = 3 , then its working fine.other wise its not working